# Having trouble with integrating factor differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=7,\quad y(0)=0 .$$

I am confused on the separation.

multiplying by $dx$ gives me

$dy+2ydx=7dx$

how then do I separated the $2ydx$?

solving for A I get

7/2−7/2e^−2x

which is correct thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: What piece of information given to you have you not yet used?

Comment: making a change of variable $u = 2y-7$ may make it easier to solve this equation.

Answer (score 0):

Separation of variables gives

> $$ \int\frac{dy}{7-2y} =\int dx +C. $$

To see that just write the ode as

> $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 7-2y. $$

**Added:**

> $$ -2 y = e^{-2x+C}-7 \implies y=\frac{7}{2}-e^{C}e^{-2x} \implies  y(x)=\frac{7}{2}-A e^{-2x}.$$

Use the initial condition to find the constant $A$.

Comment: Then integrating I believe I would have -ln(7-y)=x+C? would this be correct?

Comment: No you made a mistake. Make sure of your calculations! It should be $-\frac{1}{2} \ln(7-2y)=x+C$ and you need to determine $C$ using the initial condition.

Comment: @Alex: I already gave you the correct answer in my last comment!

Comment: I saw that after I typed that out now I am having trouble simplifying to terms of y however

Comment: Try to make the $\ln$ function on one side and then exponentiate   both sides.

Comment: ln(7-2y)=-2x+C == 7-2y=e^(-2x+C) == -2y=(e^-2x+C)-7 would seem like I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Comment: Your simplification is correct! By the way you can include your work by editing your post!

Comment: sorry I am new here but am still having trouble getting the correct answer